# Minor alignment issue in improve edit popup window

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, edits, suggested-edits

There is a minor alignment issue in the "Improve Edit" popup window. The text "hide preview" doesn't have proper margin.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: SS]

The alignment issue is not occurred, if I review a post from suggested edit review queue and clicked the "Improve Edit" button, there the content is loaded on the page instead of the popup window.

If a edit is proposed on the post, and clicked on the "edit (1)" link, in the popup window if I clicked on the "Improve Edit" button, there we can see the "hide preview" alignment issue.

**Steps to reproduce:**

> [image: GIF]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed and is now live. Thanks for the thorough report!